# Rules and restriction for toy UAV in India on very low heights ? (max 50 meter from ground )

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, regulations, dgca-india-regulations, dgca-india

We want use RC UAV to take some pictures of  heritage forts (Gadh) around Pune. Do I need a special permission for that ? I have seen some one doing it before but just for to be sure I need to know. is there any official government website that can guide us ? I am so concerned because I want to do a research project.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is effectively seeking legal advice and StackExchange is not the right place to get this.

Comment: @Simon we already had similar question and they have not been closed. This is more about aviation-related regulations rather than "advice".

Comment: @Federico Which is why close needs multiple votes ;)

Comment: @Simon I know, I was just explaining, the same way you did ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A public notice issued by the DGCA in October reads: “DGCA is in the process of formulating the regulations [and globally harmonise those] for certification & operation for use of Unmanned aircraft systems [UAS] in the Indian Civil Airspace. Till such regulations are issued, no non-government agency, organisation, or an individual will launch a UAS in Indian Civil Airspace for any purpose whatsoever.”

...

> “There are no regulatory guidelines concerning the sales and operation of such aircraft. So when a request is made for the use of drones we allow it on a ‘case-by-case’ basis. If we feel that they would not pose any security threat or cause any traffic snarls, we allow the request,” explained another senior police officer.

[The Hindu, December 24 2014](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/drones-fly-in-mumbai-despite-dgca-ban/article6720004.ece)

Comment: Thanks RedGrittyBrick instead of complaining like others you found the right answer must appreciate your searching skills plus your attitude and understanding level. Thanks a lot.